# Using bwdist (Distance transform) with a specific window size

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching

I am using bwdist in MATLAB, but I want to use a specific window size. I think MATLAB uses its default window size. Is there any other function which let me to use my own window size?

Comment: There is no concept of window size. For each pixel `bwdist` gives you the distance to the nearest non-zero pixel.

Comment: @Parag: Actually I am looking for doing Chamfer transform and found that dis function can do a similar job.

Comment: As far as I know, `bwdist` is a component of chamfer transform system

Comment: I think you guys are both wrong. Euclidean Distance transform measuring the exact distance between pixels. Since exact distance involves calculation of sqrt() it becomes computational heavy. In order to solve that issue, a Chamfer mask of 3x3 can be used to approximate the distance up to error of 8% with only liner calculations (without sqrt()). Mask of size 5x5 approximated up to ~3% error. If you want a distance transform with non-quclidian distance (for example manhattan distance) than Chamfer is completely irrelevant. And there is no window size in Matlab. It uses exact calculation

Comment: @LokeshA.R. I don't think that way. In fact in my first comment I said that there is no concept of window size in `bwdist`. 
@DanielHsH Why do you think I am wrong? I didn't have a good idea of chamfer transform but I don't think what I said for `bwdist` is wrong.

Comment: @Parag: The question was meant for Sam. Edited the comment.

Comment: @Sam: Why do you think a window is being used in bwdist function?

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean Distance transform measures the exact distance between pixels. Since exact distance involves calculation of sqrt() it becomes computational heavy.

In order to solve that issue, a Chamfer mask of 3x3 can be used to approximate the distance up to error of 8% with only liner calculations (without sqrt()). 
Mask of size 5x5 approximated up to ~3% error.

If you want a distance transform with non-quclidian distance (for example Manhattan distance) than Chamfer is completely irrelevant.

In conclusion: there is no window size in Matlab. It uses exact calculation when you ask for Euclidian distance transform. In order to approximate it one can uses quasi-euclidian distance. For other distances (chessboard/Manhattan) the calculation is precise and fast.
You cannot simulate Chamfer masks with distance transform.

In openCV - distance transform uses Chamfer mask and you can set the size of the mask. Typically 5x5 mask is used because bigger masks will yiled almost the same results (unnoticeable difference for the human eye)